# Rails 6: Updating Html With Channel Stream, Replacing Text With New Text

Tags: java, jquery, ruby-on-rails, channel

I have a channel set up in my rails project that handles incoming post requests and updates a table I created. I have a table field where I want to replace the text, and enter in the new text from the post request. I get all the requests when I do $('#').append(), however, when I use $('#').replaceWith(), it will update the text once, but not again. Is replaceWith not the optimal method?

```
    // Called when there's incoming data on the websocket for this channel
    received(data) {    

    // will only change text once. example: post1  /*will not change it to later post data */
    $('#my-partial-reference').replaceWith(data.content)

   // will post all updates, but in continuous string ex : post1post2post3post4
   //  $('#my-partial-reference').append(data.content)
  

  }
```

here is my _partial.html.erb:

```
<td id ="my-partial-reference"><%= call.callstatus %></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I got this working, and the answer was a little out of the box.

I got it working by inputting a partial as the data for my data stream.

```
 # first i created a method to accept the partial

 def post_recieved
  ActionCable.server.broadcast "call_channel",
                           content: message_render(params["CallStatus"])  
  end

  #here is a method I made to enter the data to my channel as a partial

  def message_render(message)
    my_model_ref = MyModel.first
    my_model_ref.callstatus = message

    #here i render my partial, but use the data from my temporary model

    render(partial: 'view_sub_folder/my-partial-reference', locals: {call:  my_model_ref })

  end
```

then in my channel, i replace the old partial with a new one

```
received(data) {
 $('#my-partial-reference').replaceWith(data.content)
  }
```

As far as I know, this shouldn't work. But my table is updated real time without missing a post call, does anyone know why it does? I have some guesses but I'm far from a professional at rails.